# Where are wordpress widgets assigned to page in database

Tags: wordpress

I have found the wordpress widgets in the database. But where can I assign them to a specific 'block'? Normaly you would go to appearance > widgets and drag them to the 'block'. But how can I do this from phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its usually stored in the wp_options table. Certain themes may have their own way of storing widget data too. If you're using a normal wordpress theme it should be in that table.

[Link to another thread where the answer was confirmed.](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/where-are-the-actual-contents-of-widgets-stored)

You can find an older version of the WP ER Diagram here:
[http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_options)